# Slide out NSWindow? or NSView?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I would like to know how the Found mac app is able to produce a slide out window of their menu bar app.  Anybody know where I can start looking about it?

Thanks!

Comment: Found mac app? Never heard of that one. Maybe a screenshot would help?

Comment: http://a1297.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/120/Purple/v4/59/9a/0d/599a0d7f-d77c-93ed-2376-f2eff5a0af4b/mzl.fyvobrag.800x500-75.jpg

Comment: @Till: If you search the Mac App Store for “Found”, this is the first result: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/found/id527134927

Comment: Are you referring to the list of files, or the preview panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned the menubar, I'm assuming the window is in a popover. If thats the case, [`NSPopover`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSPopover_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010720) has a set of delegate methods in [`NSPopoverDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSPopoverDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html). In these delegate methods, you will find [`-detachableWindowForPopover:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSPopoverDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSPopoverDelegate/detachableWindowForPopover%3a).

Comment: That method is called by the popover when the user drags it off of whatever it's attached to (detaching it into a separate window). For example, iCal's/Calendar's event editor. Implementing it won't help if you don't already have a popover attached to a window for the user to detach.